# Apache FTP Server remove chroot

Tags: java, apache, ftp, chroot

I am working on a new project where Apache FTP server is to be embedded in a Web App. It works perfectly well but a requirement (due to a widespread existing legacy application) is to remove the automatic chroot on the user's home directory.

**Does anyone know how I do this?**

My `user.properties` file looks like this:

```
# FTP Server properties. 
ftpserver.user.user1.userpassword=cf8d250046f84f82a1c5dfda388a355f
ftpserver.user.user1.homedirectory=/home/ftproot
ftpserver.user.user1.enableflag=true
ftpserver.user.user1.writepermission=true
ftpserver.user.user1.maxloginnumber=0
ftpserver.user.user1.maxloginperip=0
ftpserver.user.user1.idletime=0
ftpserver.user.user1.uploadrate=0
ftpserver.user.user1.downloadrate=0
```

What I'd like is for the user to not be restricted to `/home/ftproot/..` and be able to move around `/home/<other-dirs>`

A simpler way of doing this might be to change the home directory as shown below

```
ftpserver.user.user1.homedirectory=/home
```

But as mentioned, the legacy systems that will use our new app are so old and so many of them that it could cause "issues". We are trying to backfit a new app in so that these older systems won't notice any change.

In short, the removal of the chroot from the Apache FTP Server would be the simplest idea. Failing this, the amendment above might be the best option.